# RelativeLayout on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have added RelativeLayouts dynamically to my activity. The number of RelativeLayouts is equal to the number of items in my list.. below is the code:

```
RelativeLayout rt;
for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
    { 
      rt=new RelativeLayout(this);
    }
```

Now if I have 7 items in list hence 7 RelativeLayouts, I want to set click event on each of them. So I did:

```
rt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //some code
        }
    });
```

Butthe click event is working only for the last layout.. I want it on each layout.. How can I achieve it? Please help.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: you have to put click listener code in for loop.

Comment: Used `setTag()` and `getTag()` for it.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ListView` or `RecyclerView` that is the right way to implement them in android because it recycles the views, saves memory, and has alot of cool features you can use for your views. Here is a good tutorial on ListView: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
And here is one on RecyclerView:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your setOnClickListener() inside of the for loop itself.

```
RelativeLayout rt;
for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
{ 
  rt=new RelativeLayout(this);
  rt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //some code
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this part of your code

```
rt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //some code
    }
});
```

inside of the for-loop for every single RelativeLayout. The whole code should looks like:

```
RelativeLayout rt;
for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
{ 
     rt=new RelativeLayout(this);
     rt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //some code
        }
    });
    //add the rt to your parent layout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The click event work on your last layout because when the loop end, the obj `rt` contain a reference to the last layout.

One of the solutions is to create an array of those layout and and create an `onClickListener` for each one.

Another one is if your listener is the same for all the layout you can set it inside the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
    { 
      rt=new RelativeLayout(this);
      rt.setOnClickListener(myListener);
    }

OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can your do something related this...

```
    RelativeLayout rt;
for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
{ 
  rt=new RelativeLayout(this);
  rt.setTag(i);
  rt.setOnClickListener(relativeLayoutClickListener);   

});
}


OnClickListener relativeLayoutClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer i = (Integer)v.getTag();
    //based on i value do update
    }
});
```